# Javascript template literal missing variable values

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a simple template formatting program, where a user fills in certain information and my program outputs a customized letter.

```js
const name = document.getElementById('name')
const food = document.getElementById('food')
const age = document.getElementById('age')
const submitBtton = document.getElementById('submit')
const letter = document.getElementById('letter')
function output(){
  letter.textContent = 
  `Happy Birthday ${name.value}! You're turning ${age.value}
   This is a big accomplishment, we must celebrate. Are you free next week for some ${food.value}?`
}
submitBtton.addEventListener('click',output);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type = "text" id = "name" placeholder = "name">
  <input type = 'text' id = 'food' placeholder = 'food'>
  <input type = 'text' id = 'age' placeholder = 'age'>
  <button id = 'submit' type = 'button' >Submit</button>
  <button id = 'resetting' type = 'reset'>Reset</button>
</form>            
<p id = "letter"></p>
```

The above works just fine, however if everything else stays the same but I assign letter.textContent to another variable containing the template literal:

```
<script>
  const paragraph =
    `Happy Birthday ${name.value}! You're turning ${age.value}
    This is a big accomplishment, we must celebrate. Are you free next week for some ${food.value}?`` 
  function output() {letter.textContent = paragraph}
  submitBtton.addEventListener('click',output)
</script>
```

the program only works about 30% of the time. The string literal outputs fine but the variables - name, age, and food don't always show up? Why is that?

Comment: You need to get the elements each time inside the `output` function. `document.getElementById('name')` and others will only run once the way you have it.

Comment: What happens is that on page load the variables are being set and wont update when you click submit. You should write a function that updates the variable when any of the fields are updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script is getting `value` of `name`, `age` and `food` attributes once it's loaded.

```
<script>
  /**
   * This part will be executred once when the script is loaded
   *  At this phase your "name.value", "age.value", and "food.value" are empty
   * */
  const paragraph =
    `Happy Birthday ${name.value}! You're turning ${age.value}
                         This is a big accomplishment, we must celebrate. Are you free next week for 
                         some ${food.value}?`

  // This function will be called everytime, and it will return the same result
  // because "paragraph" variable didn't change
  function output() {
    letter.textContent = paragraph

  }

  submitBtton.addEventListener('click', output)
</script>
```

In Javascript, [strings pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value.): So, when you called `name.value` for example you just copied the value, and it was an empty string `""`.

So if you want to have and "updated `paragraph` value" outside your `output` function, just make it a function so it will be called every time and then it will get the new values.

Example:

```html
<form>

  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name">
  <input type='text' id='food' placeholder='food'>
  <input type='text' id='age' placeholder='age'>

  <button id='submit' type='button'>Submit</button>
  <button id='resetting' type='reset'>Reset</button>
</form>

<p id="letter"></p>

<script>
  const name = document.getElementById('name')
  const food = document.getElementById('food')
  const age = document.getElementById('age')

  const submitBtton = document.getElementById('submit')
  const letter = document.getElementById('letter')

  function getParagraph() {
   return `Happy Birthday ${name.value}! You're turning ${age.value}
                     This is a big accomplishment, we must celebrate. Are you free next week for 
                     some ${food.value}?`
  }

  function output() {
    letter.textContent = getParagraph()
  }
  submitBtton.addEventListener('click', output)
</script>
```